# how to change orbit direction when button clicked?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, direction, orbit

I'm trying to develop a simple game.
My question is I am using following code to move object in clockwise orbit. I'd like to change the direction of the object to counterclockwise orbit when a button is pressed.

```cs
//Increase the speed from 1 to 10 over 60 second.
currentSpeed = Mathf.SmoothStep(1f, 10f, time / accelerationTime);
// Decides speed of the ball.
newSpeed += Time.deltaTime * currentSpeed;
// Move the ball in Circular position accordingly speed.
transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Sin(newSpeed) * 40, 5, Mathf.Cos(newSpeed) * 40);
//Increase time with actual time.
time += Time.deltaTime;
if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) )
{
    transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(newSpeed) * 40, 5, Mathf.Sin(newSpeed) * 40);
}
else { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Each time the button is clicked, multiply `newSpeed` by `-1`. This should flip its value to either negative or positive depending on its current value causing `Vector3(Mathf.Cos(newSpeed) * 40, 5, Mathf.Sin(newSpeed) * 40)` to also flip its result and eventually changing the orbit direction.

```
if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) )
{
    //Flip direction
    newSpeed *= -1f;

    transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(newSpeed) * 40, 5, Mathf.Sin(newSpeed) * 40);
}
```

Comment: it changes but only for one frame.